# Send parameters to the php file that I load events

Tags: php, events, parameters, fullcalendar

I'm trying to pass a parameter to my query that loads the events in my calendar, my calendar is set as follows:

```
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                height: 450,
                contentHeight: 200,
                aspectRatio: 3,
                    theme: true,
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            editable: true,
disableDragging: true,
firstDay: 1,
weekends: true,
defaultEventMinutes:30,
monthNames: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio','Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'],
monthNameShort: ['Ene', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'May', 'Jun','Jul', 'Ago', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dic'],
dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miercoles','Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sabado'],
dayNamesShort: ['Dom', 'Lun', 'Mar', 'Mie', 'Jue', 'Vie', 'Sab'],
buttonText: {
today: 'hoy',
month: 'mes',
week: 'semana',
day: 'dia'

},
allDaySlot: false,
allDayText: 'Todo el dia',
axisFormat: 'H:mm',




            events: "json-events.php?user="+$("#list").val(),
            timeFormat: 'H:mm{ - H:mm}',
            eventDrop: function(event, delta) {
                alert(event.title + ' was moved ' + delta + ' days\n' +
                    '(should probably update your database)');
            },

            loading: function(bool) {
                if (bool) $('#loading').show();
                else $('#loading').hide();
            },
eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {

    //alert('Event: ' + calEvent.title);
    //alert('Coordinates: ' + jsEvent.pageX + ',' + jsEvent.pageY);
    //alert('View: ' + view.name);
    nombre = prompt('Introduce tu nombre','[ nombre del usuario ]');
    //alert(nombre);
    event.title=nombre;

    // change the border color just for fun
    $(this).css('border-color', 'red');

},
dayClick: function( date, allDay, jsEvent, view ) {
    $("#input_date").val($.fullCalendar.formatDate( date,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss' ));
    $("#end_date").val($.fullCalendar.formatDate( date,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss' ));
    jQuery('#form_crea_evento').dialog('open');
}


        });
```

in this line -> **events: "json-events.php?user="+$("#list").val(),**

"list" is a drop down list that I'm taking the value that is selected, and the onchange event refechEvents released a calendar and my PHP script is called perfectly but the sending parameter to get is not updated.

As I can do to pass a parameter to the php class that I load events?

Thanks and greetings

Comment: What is the "sending parameter to get?"

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use this selector to get the selected value from your list:

```
 $('#list option:selected').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found that you have to stick to the documentation format for passing a variable to the php "feed" file.  Adding the variable via the url (/myfeed.php?variable=something) didn't work for me.

So try passing the variable in the data: section like this.  Plug in your user variable value where the 'something' is.

```
events: {
    url: 'json-events.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        user: 'something'
    }
}
```